# How to format and select randoms from a range in python

Tags: python, random, printing, range, decimal

how do I select one of the produced decimal values and cast it to a variable.

```
for i in range(10):
    print (random.random() * (0.909 - 0.101) + 0.101)
```

Also how do i make that variable have only three decimal place it has to be in the variable not the print I should then be able to simply do this instead of generating the decimals in the print i would like to do it in a variable and choose a value?

```
print = (myVar)
```

Comment: Orthogonal to your question, but why not use `random.uniform(0.101, 0.909)`? That's equivalent to your expression, but easier to write (and read).

Comment: thanks will try good stuff lots of great answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just assign your random instead of printing it, and round it to 3 decimal places:

```
myVar = round(random.random() * (0.909 - 0.101) + 0.101, 3)
```

Comment: zwer perfect and efficient the others are good too but yours takes up less space and performs it with out to much thinking

Comment: @GoulouhAnwar - you might want to consider accepting the answer for future reference.

Comment: @zwer looks like you got downvoted too. Someone isn't happy with us answering this. I love trolls. Especially since the downvoting came for the ones that were upvoted only.

Comment: @idjaw - If somebody doesn't have better things to do than go around and downvote my answers (got several of them in a short succession) there's nothing much I can do than pity them.

Comment: @zwer That's unfortunate. If you *just* got a bunch of downvotes in a short period of time, you might get lucky and have them reversed since it might be caught by the serial downvoting mechanism.

Comment: @idjaw - I don't think several downvotes would classify as _serial_, I'm pretty sure I even know who it is (given that he was the only participant on all the questions I got downvotes for) but I can't be bothered to quibble  over something as trivial as SO rep with immature internet strangers. If that makes them happy, downvote away I say...

Answer (score 7):

You are looking to perform the following with your print function:

```
print("{0:.3f}".format(result))
```

As noted in the comments, an alternative to support the old-style string formatting if one chooses to use *that* method. The solution can be achieved with this as well:

```
print("%0.3f" % result)
```

Using that formatter will only print the result to three decimals.

Demo:

```
from random import random

for n in range(10):
    result = random() * (0.909 - 0.101) + 0.101
    print("{0:.3f}".format(result))
```

Output:

```
0.323
0.721
0.665
0.831
0.141
0.297
0.643
0.456
0.716
0.320
```

Comment: Just FYI to anyone who cannot use `str.format()` or prefers old-style string formatting, the same output in the answer can be achieved using: `"%0.3f" % result`.

Answer (score 0):

You can format it in the string by specifying the decimal places like this with the 3.

```
>>> num = 3.123468
>>> "{:.3f}".format(num)
"3.123"
```